# Do arrays that get allocated on the stack within the scope of a function always get deallocated when leaving the function?

Tags: c++, g++, allocation

Let's say I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
void f() {
  int arr[10];
}

int main() {
  f();
  f();
}
```

Does the array `arr` get deallocated once we leave the scope of `f()`, even though we will call it again? Also, if we only call `f()` once, I'm assuming it gets deallocated when leaving the scope of `f()`, but someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

I also realize that this may be compiler-related question so I've included g++ as a tag. Thanks.

Comment: @YunfeiChen your comment doesn't seem to relate to my question. My question is not based on what the function does. I am using that code as a way to illustrate my question in a more visual way. All that is needed to know is that an array is allocated on the stack in some function, and nothing is returned once we leave the scope of that function. You also specify something about "which method is better", but I haven't mentioned differing methods, so i don't really understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Well the thing is if you do not tell me what the arrays are for it is very hard to tell you what is better, do you plan on doing a mergeSort with them later or do you plan on using heapSort or do you plan on creating some higher dimension arrays, dynamic or not it really depends on the usage....

Comment: Again, you say "what is better", but I haven't mentioned anything about different methods. I'm not sure if you understand my question. All I was asking was if an array allocated on the stack in a function gets deallocated once we leave the scope of the function, even when calling the function again. It doesn't matter what happens within the function. If I run a sorting algorithm on the array within the function, it's completely irrelevant. View the accepted answer for more info.

Comment: Well you asked "Thanks for your reply. So the reason why I ask is because I am initializing multiple arrays in a function that gets called thousands of times, and I am wondering if it would be better to just have those arrays be static so that they are not deallocated when the function leaves which should speed up the process. Does that seem like a good idea?" in your reply so I just felt like I needed to comment on that....

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were referring to one of my comments, considering you posted your comment under my original question and not under the answer, where my comment was. In any case, the question has been answered, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually it does indeed since `arr` has automatic storage duration. (For example, if you were to return a pointer to an element of that array, then the behavior on dereferencing that pointer in the caller would be undefined.)

Whether or not the compiler chooses an appropriate optimisation based on the *as-if* rule is another matter.

With g++ set to -O3, you can expect your entire program to be compiled to `int main(){}`. Check the generated assembly if you're in any doubt.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the reason why I ask is because I am initializing multiple arrays in a function that gets called thousands of times, and I am wondering if it would be better to just have those arrays be static so that they are not deallocated when the function leaves which should speed up the process. Does that seem like a good idea?

Comment: Allocation on the stack / automatic storage duration usually is not an expensive process. Typically it requires an increment of a register.

Comment: @JohnnyD27 Allocation of memory on the stack is just moving the stack pointer further. It takes no extra work if the objects are not initialized.

Comment: @JohnnyD27: Absolutely don't optimise prematurely like this. Making them `static` could be harmful: you might end up breaking your threading model for example. `thread_local` might only be marginally better, and both carry overheads of their own. If you think the automatic array is a performance bottleneck, then use a profiling tool.

Comment: This makes alot of sense. So I will keep the arrays allocated on the stack. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 2):

You are not wrong. The array gets allocated every time the function is called and de-allocated every time the function ends. Although allocation/de-allocation on the stack is essentially free. Also with an `int` array you won't even pay for constructors to run on the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what @Bhathsheba said whenever you go out of the scope that memory (stack) is not automatically invalidated it's just that you give the freedom of deleting the stack based on other requirements. If there is no other process running then the stack might not get deleted. So it depends on the situation.

Comment: "_If there is no other process running then the stack might not get deleted_" - Can you expand on that a little bit? It sounds interesting.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I could be wrong, but I think Sai meant that once we leave the scope of the function, the data from the array on the stack might not get cleared, even though that space can now be used by some process.